# "I shout into the heavens and weep" in Spanish

Tags: traducción

How do I say "I shout into the heavens and weep" in Spanish?

> He shouts into the heavens above and put a spell on my girlfriend.

My attempt :

> Él grita en los cielos arribas y pone un hechizo en mi novia.

Comment: I do not understand the context you want to say that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

En España tenemos una expresión que es:

> Puso el grito en el cielo.

La cual significa protestar por algo, quejarse.

Ej:

> El marisco que le sirvieron estaba caducado y cuando se dió cuenta puso el grito en el cielo.

Sin embargo en este caso, y por el contexto, creo que la traducción adecuada sería:

> Él clamó a los cielos y hechizó a mi novia.

O bien:

> Él gritó a los cielos y hechizó a mi novia.

Normalmente, cuando se hace un llamamiento de "poder" hacia arriba, hacia fuerzas elementales (cielo, infierno, estrellas, el agua, el viento, el mar), se suele usar el plural, por ejemplo:

> Clamó a **los cielos**.
>
> Moises separó **las aguas** del mar Rojo.
>
> Que callen **los vientos** cuando yo hablo.

Hay excepciones a esto dependiendo del contexto, para lo cual es mejor suponer la traducción entera:

> Le pido al cielo que nos dé salud este año (se refiere a Dios, no a "los cielos" como algo elemental).

Comment: Sorry for the spanish-only answer, I'm not sure to know how to  translate it to english properly.

Comment: pair of accents missing :) in "el".

Answer (score 1):

`El gritó en el cielo y puso un hechizo sobre mi novia.`

Is the only way that sentence make sense for me, I know the verb `shout` is in present but in Spanish don't sound good to me the translation, he first shouted into the heavens above and after put a spell on your girlfriend

Answer (score 0):

Para gritar en el cielo tienes que estar previamente EN (dentro de) el cielo, y lo que se adivina por la frase original es que quien grita está en la tierra, y grita desde allí al cielo (*heavens above*), por lo que sería más bien: "Gritó al cielo".

Si le quieres dar un poco de dramatismo, usa mejor "Clamó a los cielos" como sugiere @Arkana.

Por otra parte, el (poco) contexto de la frase sugiere que la persona que clama a los cielos lo hace porque no tiene poder para hechizar a la muchacha, así que no me suena del todo bien la segunda parte "y hechizó a mi novia". Quien "hechizo a mi novia" no fue la persona que clamó a los cielos, sino "los cielos" (o alguien que mora en los cielos), así que propongo esta traducción:

> Clamó a los cielos y mi novia fue hechizada

Aquí la forma pasiva sugiere dos eventos causales: primero alguien clama a los cielos, y en consecuencia, la novia es hechizada, pero no dice que la persona que clama y el ente que hechiza a la muchacha sean la misma persona.

Si en verdad son ambas la misma persona, entonces usa la forma activa:

> Clamó a los cielos y hechizó a mi novia